# Get python stdlib version, not interpreter version

Tags: python, version, lib

Is there a kind of seperate version number for the python `stdlib`? I know that I can get the python *interpreter* version using:

```
import sys
sys.version
```

But is there something similar for the python stdlib? Or does the version number always match?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How could they be different?

Comment: Maybe when the interpreter gets bugfixes/new features, but the stdlib remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Historically the standard library is an *imprescriptable part of every Python distribution*. The latter has a version and it helps to distinguish old distributions from the recent ones. Hence, not obvious, but historically - the standard library has the same version as a whole Python distribution.

When you read something like *'batteries included'* in Python - this means not the galvanic cells (surprisingly), but mostly [its stdlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Libraries)